# .loc deleting rows instead of locating Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to locate rows based on two conditions in a pandas df.

Code"

```
def type_filter():
    TRADER_READER['Instrument Type'] = TRADER_READER.loc[(TRADER_READER['Instrument Type'] == 'Equity Option')
                                                         | (TRADER_READER['Instrument Type'] == 'Equity')]
    print(TRADER_READER)
```

Result:

```
638  2019-12-12 09:45:42            Trade  ...         13.0         PUT
639  2019-12-10 17:00:00   Money Movement  ...          NaN         NaN
```

I literally copy pasted the code into a function and it now has deleted that entire column. Before, it grabbed only those rows. I should not see the row with 'money momvement' as the value for the Instrument Type column is NaN.

I am at a complete and total loss how to put these lines into a function and everything is breaking. Why can't I put this into a function?

Answer (score 0):

TRADER_READER['Instrument Type'] is referenced twice in your `loc` statement. Instrument Type can't equal 'Equity Option' and 'Equity' simultaneously

If you want a boolean for each row, then you need to create a new column, say 'IS_EQUITY', rather than overwriting the same column (TRADER_READER['Instrument Type']) with an assignment.

If you are just trying to get a subset of the rows in the dataframe that meet your condition, then you would write

```
equity = TRADER_READER.loc[TRADER_READER['Instrument Type'].isin(['Equity', 'Equity Option']), :]
```

Comment: When I do `|` it still comes back the same.

Comment: Also, why would it delete all values of the column?

Comment: You are effectively assigning NaN to every row of TRADER_READER['Instrument Type'] by applying this function because you are assigning the result of a loc operation that is impossible to satisfy (being equal to two different values). If you want to filter the dataframe, call .loc without assigning it to the same column.